# Laravel 4 - Get first image of images in file input array before uploading

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this file input:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
```

In my controller I upload them this way:

```
 $x = 0;
 foreach(Input::file('images') as $file) {

                    $filename = $x.'.'.$file->guessClientExtension();
                    //dest, name
                    if (!file_exists($thepath)) {
                        mkdir($thepath, 0777, true);
                    }
                    $uploadflag = $file->move($thepath,$filename);

                    $is_main = ($x==0) ? true : NULL; //Know who's first img

                    $img_submit = DB::table('images')->insert(array(
                        'image_id'          => $filename,
                        'is_main'           => $is_main
                    ));

                    if($uploadflag) {
                        $uploadedfiles[] = $filename;
                    }
                $x++;
 }
```

I have a plugin wich sorts them out the way I want, if I do a print_r to the form I get:

```
Array (
[title] => 
[images] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2.png
        [1] => 1.png
        [2] => 3.png
        [3] => 4.png
        [4] => 5.png
    )

[submit] => Submit
)
```

You can notice that the image with the name 2.png (wich I sorted it to be first) is being accomodated in the position [0] of the array as expected. But when I try to upload it I get the variable $is_main set to another image. **How can I indentify in the array position [0] to be the main image?**

I've tried iterating with $x so that when $x is 0 in the foreach loop I set the first image to be the main one, but looks like in the process the array gets "dissacomodated"

EDIT: If you could at least tell me how to get the first image in the array in  PHP I would easily know how to do it with Laravel :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Use reset()**

```
$files = Input::file('images');

foreach($files  as $file):

        $filename = $x.'.'.$file->guessClientExtension();

        # Destination, Name
        if (!file_exists($thepath))
            mkdir($thepath, 0777, true);

        $uploadflag = $file->move($thepath,$filename);

        # reset() files to see if current file is the first one
        $is_main = ($file == reset($files)) ? true : NULL;

        $img_submit = DB::table('images')->insert([
            'image_id' => $filename,
            'is_main'  => $is_main
        ]);

        if($uploadflag) 
            $uploadedfiles[] = $filename;

endforeach;
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution but It's not working this way unfortunately :(

Comment: Why is it  not working for you?  What is the issue? try `$files[0] == $file`

Comment: I can successfully upload the images and store them to database, but what I want is to set the first image ( in the array would be position[0] ) as the main one so $is_main would be set to TRUE, I tried your code but I still get the same result - the images are stored in the order I uploaded them but not in the order I arranged them with this plugin: http://bit.ly/1BPGG8v (Example #4)

Comment: If I do **$is_main = ($files[0]) ? true : NULL;** as you mentioned, all images are set to TRUE

Comment: @Daniel I didn't say to do that.  I said `$files[0] == $file` not `$files[0]`

Comment: I still get the same result doing **$is_main = ($files[0] == $file) ? true : NULL;**

Comment: @Daniel looking at the plugin, since this is using AJAX, where are you receiving the sort request? in JSON format?  The problem is not with my code it is with your request.  You need to grab the JSON data that the AJAX plug is sending over.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the current plugin works via AJAX and submits the images instantly. I contacted the programmer and he personalized it for me, now I can submit the images when I click submit and there's no work done via AJAX. I handle the image upload via PHP with the original script I posted, the print_r() I showed as well is what I get when I click submit

Comment: Do me a favor and `print_r(Input::file('images'));` the images in your controller and tell me waht you get.  Add the the code to your question.

Comment: I actually contacted him and just answered me a few minutes ago with the same exact solution I'm doing in my question, he uses the $x variable to incremenent so when it's equal to 0 then that would be the main image wich is not working for me interestingly

Comment: will do, give me a few mins to try it I have a really extensive form

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is the output: http://pastebin.com/x73bnCwE the order is actually not as expected, you can notice the "originalName" for each iteration is in order "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png" when in reality the order I set to them was "2.png", "1.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png"

Comment: Also it's worth to mention that this order only happens in Laravel, when I tried in PHP first the order was working as expected

Comment: Ok good, so where did you get the first print_r? in your question?

Comment: In the original .zip I received before implementing it to Laravel, but in that file ajax was activated when I clicked submit and then I erased the automatic ajax upload so I could handle it via PHP but conserving the features for sorting, selecting main image, etc... Okay, now I noticed it has to do with the changes and it's not possible now with PHP :/ I'm really confused on what to do right now

Comment: It is possible and Laravel is still PHP there is no difference between PHP and Laravel.  Laravel is a PHP framework.  Like  I said before, it looks like you lost functionality when AJAX was taken away.

Comment: Yep that was it, I lost the sorting functionality.... Hmm, thanks ALOT for your help, I'll try to figure this out somehow :/

Comment: @Daniel your best bet is to implement AJAX the way the plugin was designed.

Comment: I managed to implement it again in PHP and disabling the ajax, the output (the print_r) was working as expected but the first image is still not working as expected. Would you mind to quickly check it if I send you the code (it's a really simple and clean code) via email? Please let me know, thank you